# How to use Dexie.js inside of dedicated worker?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker, dexie

I have a function that fetch a JSON data via `window.fetch` and put it inside `IndexedDB` table via `db.table.bulkPut(array_of_data)`.
It takes more than 10 seconds to do that because of large amount of data and it blocks UI and makes UX bad.
I have decided to run this task in a `Worker`, but I have not found any examples how can I make that with Dexie.js or directly with `IndexedDB`

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @kaiido for link this is an answer -=> https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/789